# Kendo combobox textField

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Is it possible, using Kendo Combobox, to have something like

```
<kendo-combobox textField="varA & varB">
...
</kendo-combobox>
```

where varA and varB are two strings?

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a JSX question. Yes it is possible, but the syntax is different:

```
<kendo-combobox textField={varA + " " + varB}>
...
</kendo-combobox>
```

This way you are concatenating two strings with a space inbetween.

Every time you want to reference variable, functions, etc. you use curly brackets to indicate to JSX, that a Javascript expression will be executed.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't working. May can help this way : <kendo-combobox 
  [data]="myData" textField=myFunction(myData)> any way to do this?

Comment: why should this not work? It's perfectly valid JSX. What you are proposing in your comment is not valid JSX, correct it to `<kendo-combobox data={myData} textField={myFunction(myData)}>`.

Comment: Ah okay, this is angular, sorry. Then it should be possible to use it like this: `<kendo-combobox textField="varA + ' ' + varB">`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional field to each entry containing the text you want to display and then use this field as the `textField`. This is the standard approach.

If you're compiling the data on a server you can do this either client-side or server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why people say this is jsx? anyway, If this is angular, you need double curly to let the angular compiler knows that this is a javascript expression

```
<kendo-combobox textField={{varA + " " + varB}}>
...
</kendo-combobox>
```

Comment: Compiler says is missing the end of file. Tried to format this code in every way possible. Still errors.

Comment: There's nothing else than text and other things that are not in relation with this. It's just how to have the `textField` with two strings instead of one.

Comment: Yes. My problem with combox is just if don't put one string

Comment: Not sure if this is an interpolation issue, if you declare a new variable, concat and assign the values into it, would that fix your issue? My guess is it will still break. Would you still get the same error?